# Adding favorites to a FBFriendPickerViewController

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch

I have a FBFriendPickerViewController that prompts my user for a selection of friends. Quite often the friends are the same, so I would like to create a section in the top called "Favorites" in which I add some of the most used participants.

How can I get access to the friend list and add users?